# Attaching a PKPass to Email in Code

Tags: ios, email, nsdata, passbook, passslot

I am using PassSlot which creates a Pass on the fly that can be added to passbook.  I am trying to get it downloaded to the device to allow attaching to an email.  Here is what I have so far:

```
[PassSlot passFromTemplateWithName:@"LoveCouponCards" withValues:values pass:^(PSPass *pass) {
    [PassSlot downloadPass:pass pass:^(PSPass *pass) {
        PKPass *pkpass = [pass performSelector:@selector(pass)];
        NSLog(@"Pass: %@", pkpass);


        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;


        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"friend@example.com"];


        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];


        [picker addAttachmentData:pkpass mimeType:@"application/vnd.apple.pkpass" fileName:@"HI"];

        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody = \\
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];


    }];
}];
```

The issue is that in the addAttachment part for the email, it throws an error that NSData can't relate to PKPass basically.  How can I get pass converted to NSData so I can attach it?

UPDATE:

I tried doing

```
 NSURL *url = pkpass.passURL;
 NSData *so = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

and then putting 'so' as the addAttachment, but it attached nothing to the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the PassKit library does not provide a way to get back the NSData from a PKPass.

We already provide an [API call](http://www.passslot.com/developer/api/resources/showPass) that allows you to get the raw data of a pass. 
We will extend our PassSlot SDK with a method that allows you to get the NSData without having the manually call this API method.

**Update**

The new SDK version 0.5 is now released. You can attach the pass with the following code:

```
[PassSlot passFromTemplateWithName:@"LoveCouponCards" withValues:values pass:^(PSPass *pass) {
    [PassSlot downloadPass:pass pass:^(PSPass *pass) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [picker setToRecipients:@[@"friend@example.com"]];
        [picker addAttachmentData:pass.data mimeType:@"application/vnd.apple.pkpass" fileName:@"LoveCouponCard.pkpass"];
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the `passURL` property of `PKPass` doesn't quite work the way you think. It *is not* a URL to the pass itself. It is a URL that opens up the Passbook app and loads up that requested pass.

You can *create* a `PKPass` with `NSData`, but you can't reverse that process. It sounds as if you are trying to get a pass on device, and then e-mail it. That's not allowed - if it was, people could easily copy and distribute passes around (which isn't necessarily a good thing).

If you want to e-mail a user a pass you need to do it server, rather than client side. I'm afraid that what you're trying to do isn't possible using `PassKit`. Sorry!

Comment: So, using pass slot services, it creates pass combining a template on their server with info from the user. No way to really email that instead of just building on the device then?  Kind of kills idea for app I had.

Comment: I would suggest that you ask PassSlot to provide an API method that gives you the raw NSData. I'm not familiar with their library, but I assume it's not open source (if it is you could probably do this yourself).